# Didn't understand relationship 'OpportunityLineItems' in FROM part of query call

Tags: opportunity-lineitem

I am trying the below query but it results in

> "Didnt understand relationship OpportunityLineItem".

```
SELECT Id, LastModifiedDate, Account.Id, Account.Name, Owner.Email,
       UserRecordAccess.HasReadAccess ,UserRecordAccess.HasEditAccess,
       UserRecordAccess.HasDeleteAccess,
       (SELECT id, productCode, product2Id, 
               pricebookEntryId, quantity, totalPrice, unitPrice 
        FROM OpportunityLineItems),
  from Opportunity where IsClosed=false
```

Comment: looks like you are using `OpportunityLineItems` not `OpportunityLineItem` ?

Comment: @Ratan that's fine I guess since that's the plural version to be used in inner query

Comment: @highfive yeah It is bit confusing. Nitin posted question with `OpportunityLineItems`. This should be `OpportunityLineItem`

Answer (score 3):

Try below code. You were having an extra comma after the closing bracket

```
SELECT Id, LastModifiedDate, Account.Id, Account.Name, Owner.Email,
       UserRecordAccess.HasReadAccess ,UserRecordAccess.HasEditAccess,
       UserRecordAccess.HasDeleteAccess,
       (SELECT id, productCode, product2Id, 
               pricebookEntryId, quantity, totalPrice, unitPrice 
        FROM OpportunityLineItems)
  from Opportunity where IsClosed=false
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.                                                                                   I am using OpportunityLineItems in the query and the error is 
Didn't understand relationship 'OpportunityLineItems' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.', fields=null}

Answer (score 0):

Please try the updated query :

```
[SELECT Id, LastModifiedDate, Account.Id, Account.Name, Owner.Email, 
 UserRecordAccess.HasReadAccess, UserRecordAccess.HasEditAccess, 
 UserRecordAccess.HasDeleteAccess, (SELECT id, productCode, product2Id,
 pricebookEntryId, quantity, totalPrice, unitPrice FROM OpportunityLineItems)
 from Opportunity where IsClosed = false];
```

Comment: I used the below query but still the same problem                                SELECT+Id,LastModifiedDate,(SELECT+id,productCode,product2Id,pricebookEntryId,quantity,totalPrice,unitPrice+FROM+OpportunityLineItems)+from+Opportunity+where+IsClosed=false

Comment: where you are using this query ?

Comment: Hi Nilesh, 
I am using this query through a Java Program to sync Opportunities and OpportunityLineItems . Below is a snippet of the code for your reference
Response response = client.target(appConnection.getInstanceURL()+"/services/data/v30.0/query?q=SELECT+Id,LastModifiedDate," +                "(SELECT+id,productCode,product2Id,pricebookEntryId,quantity,totalPrice,unitPrice+FROM+OpportunityLineItems)" +from+Opportunity")
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).header(AUTHORIZATION, BEARER + " " + accessToken)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();;

Comment: We are trying to fetch Opportunities and LineItems for different users who register on our application. It looks some of the users dont have access to OpportunityLineItem . When I run the describe query for OpportunityLineItem for such users I receive a Resource Doesnot Exists error . For Users who have access the describe query returns the OpportunityLineItem details. Does anyone know how I can remove access for OpportunityLineItem to relplicate the problem on my salesforce account